# Add conditional statement in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
WITH grouped_messages AS
(SELECT
   um.conversation_id,
   array_agg(json_build_object('message', um.message, 'sent_at', um.created_at))
 FROM user_messages um
   INNER JOIN users_conversations c ON c.conversation_id = um.conversation_id
 WHERE c.user_id = '#{user_id}' AND um.user_id != '#{user_id}' #{ "and um.created_at >= '#{timestamp}'" IF TIMESTAMP}
 GROUP BY um.conversation_id
),
    senders AS
  (SELECT
     gm.conversation_id,
     json_build_object('id', u.id, 'user_name', u.user_name, 'avatar',
                       ('https://my-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/public/uploads/user/' || u.id :: TEXT ||
                        '/avatar.jpg')) AS sender
   FROM grouped_messages AS gm
     INNER JOIN users_conversations c ON c.conversation_id = gm.conversation_id
     INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id
   WHERE u.id != '#{user_id}'
  )
SELECT json_object_agg(grouped_messages.conversation_id,
                       json_build_object('new_messages', grouped_messages.array_agg, 'sender', senders.sender))
FROM grouped_messages
  INNER JOIN senders ON senders.conversation_id = grouped_messages.conversation_id
```

Which outputs, for example:

```
{
    "62": {
        "new_messages": [
            {
                "message": "some",
                "sent_at": "2016-05-30T20:19:53.786024"
            },
            {
                "message": null,
                "sent_at": "2016-05-30T20:19:26.408814"
            }
        ],
        "sender": {
            "id": "e4ba308b-a5cf-47ad-b8d6-d774eb325411",
            "user_name": null,
            "avatar": "https://my-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/public/uploads/user/e4ba308b-a5cf-47ad-b8d6-d774eb325411/avatar.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I need is to have a conditional statement in this query.

If u (user) avatar is not NULL then apply this `'https://my-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/public/uploads/user/' || u.id::text || '/avatar.jpg'`, otherwise just insert ':null' string (so that any JSON parser recognizes it as a null object).

Not sure how to put this if-else here in select statement and also how to ensure that part about JSON parser.

Comment: Have you tried `case when u is not null 'your URL string'`?

Comment: @venkatKA, not user itself but field avatar

Comment: Well, u.avatar is not null

Comment: Do you want `null` to come back or a specific null-like string?  I can tell you that you can safely bring back null in JSON, which would be the *strongest* indication that a column is null.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me:

```
        (SELECT gm.conversation_id, json_build_object('id', u.id, 'user_name', u.user_name,
        'avatar', (
         CASE WHEN u.avatar IS NULL THEN ':null'
         ELSE ('https://my-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/public/uploads/user/' || u.id::text || '/avatar.jpg')
         END))
```

You can provide case-statement in SELECT block as if it were value (with optional `AS`).

Comment: Your actual answer is buried underneath a mountain of code.  Would you mind extracting the actual *solution* portion of it into something easily accessible?  I'm sure others out there would love to see your CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use of the [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) expression.  In this scenario, you want to return either a hard URL to their avatar if the `avatar` field is not null, and `NULL` otherwise.

This is accomplished thus (omitting the other portions of the query for readability):

```
json_build_object('id', u.id, 'user_name', u.user_name,
                  'avatar',
                   CASE WHEN u.avatar IS NULL
                     THEN NULL
                   ELSE
                     (
                       'https://my-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/public/uploads/user/'
                       || u.id :: TEXT ||
                       '/avatar.jpg') END) AS sender
```